# singleton class design in java for creating only 10 instances only

Tags: java

I have to create a singleton class and besides this I have to make sure that not more than 
10 instances of the class to be created the moment it go create the 11 instance it should throw the exception , i have come up with the below design pls advise is it correct te only issue seems to me is where it will throw the exception , please advise .

```
public final class LazySingleton {
    private static volatile LazySingleton instance = null;


     private int counter = 0; // use to track the count of instance 

    // private constructor
    private LazySingleton() {
    }

    public static LazySingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null || counter<=10) {
            synchronized (LazySingleton.class) {
                instance = new LazySingleton();
                counter ++;
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, I think you need an array...

Comment: Make `counter` as *static* variable.

Comment: This doesn't even compile, does it?

Comment: This is not thread safe, multiple threads attempting to getInstance at the same time will cause the counter to raise above 10. Your check and set need to be in the same synchronised block

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a [multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern). In Java, that might look something like

[image: Multiton UML from Wikipedia entry]

```
public final class LazySingleton {
    private static final int MAX = 10;
    private static LazySingleton[] instances = new LazySingleton[MAX];
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            instances[i] = new LazySingleton(i);
        }
    }
    private int count;

    private static int counter = 0; // use to track the count of instance

    // private constructor
    private LazySingleton(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public static synchronized LazySingleton getInstance() {
        if (counter < MAX) {
            return instances[counter++];
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Out of new instances.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make counter a `static` variable. So that it is shared with all the other instances. If in one instance you increment the variable, the others will see it too.

Put the incrementation in the constructor, and at the end, check with a if statement, if `counter` is above 10, if it is, thrown an exception

Comment: Yes, but what if you have created 9 instances, and 2 separate threads call getInstance?

Comment: Yyes.  Same issue that David pointed out.  The synchronized block is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Make `counter` a `static` variable so that all instances of `LazySingleton` share the same value.  Then in the constructor of of `LazySingleton` you can check

```
if (counter > 10) {
    //throw desired exception
}
```

Also Make sure to increment `counter` in the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not singleton anymore, that's a factory class, because you have no access to other last objects, you have only reference to current one.

buy the way, you must set counter static, also change the if statement as this

```
synchronized (LazySingleton.class) {
    if (instance == null || counter < 10) {
            instance = new LazySingleton();
            counter ++;
         }
    else{
            throw new yourCustomException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ::

the class you want to make singleton.

```
private static SingleTon _inst = null;
private static Map<SingleTon, Integer> map = new HashMap<SingleTon, Integer>();


private SingleTon()
{

}

public static synchronized SingleTon _instance()throws Exception
{


         if(map.size()>0)
         {
             System.out.println("Okay Object is there");
         if(!map.containsValue(10))
         {
           int temp = map.get(_inst)+1;
            map.put(_inst, temp);
            return   _inst;

         }else
         {
             throw new Exception("you reached limit");
         }
    }else
    {
        _inst = new SingleTon();
        map.put(_inst,1);
        return _inst;
    }


}
```

Calling thread .. Try with different threads.

```
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("*** Calling NUmber "+i+" Object ::: "+SingleTon._instance());
        }
```

**Output**

```
             *** Calling NUmber 0 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
               Okay Object is there
              *** Calling NUmber 1 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
              Okay Object is there
              *** Calling NUmber 2 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
               Okay Object is there
              *** Calling NUmber 3 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
             Okay Object is there
             *** Calling NUmber 4 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
            Okay Object is there
             *** Calling NUmber 5 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
            Okay Object is there
            *** Calling NUmber 6 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
            Okay Object is there
            *** Calling NUmber 7 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
           Okay Object is there
          *** Calling NUmber 8 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
         Okay Object is there
        *** Calling NUmber 9 Object ::: com.comparison.test.SingleTon@1befab0
      Okay Object is there
             Exception occuredyou reached limit
      java.lang.Exception: you reached limit
                at com.comparison.test.SingleTon._instance(SingleTon.java:31)
                at com.comparison.test.Hell.main(Hell.java:97)
```